# How to fix issue Akka version is not supported by Typesafe Console for running typesafe console in Play 2.4.2 version?

Tags: playframework, sbt, akka, typesafe, typesafe-console

I am trying to setup typesafe console to track akka actors and nodes. Tried to find documentation for Play version 2.4.2, but didn't find exact help. I added below config :

```
Plugin.sbt : addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-atmos" % "0.3.2")
build.sbt : atmosSettings
```

When i run activator complie, then get below error:

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Akka version is not supported by Typesafe Console: 2.4-M2
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at com.typesafe.sbt.atmos.AtmosRun$.supportedAkkaVersion(AtmosRun.scala:65)
at com.typesafe.sbt.atmos.AtmosRun$$anonfun$selectAkkaVersion$1.apply(AtmosRun.scala:58)
at com.typesafe.sbt.atmos.AtmosRun$$anonfun$selectAkkaVersion$1.apply(AtmosRun.scala:58)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at com.typesafe.sbt.atmos.AtmosRun$.selectAkkaVersion(AtmosRun.scala:58)
at com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAtmos$$anonfun$atmosDefaultSettings$26.apply(SbtAtmos.scala:159)
at com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAtmos$$anonfun$atmosDefaultSettings$26.apply(SbtAtmos.scala:159)
```

How to fix this issue?
Is typesafe console not supporting Play 2.4.2 version? Is there any other tool to track Akka nodes in real time to keep track of actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development of Console has been [discountinued](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/typesafe-console) by Typesafe.  You can fork and fix or, alternatively...

- [Kamon](http://kamon.io/)
- [Akka Tracing](https://github.com/levkhomich/akka-tracing) (which uses [Zipkin](http://twitter.github.io/zipkin/))
- [Grafana](http://grafana.org/)
- [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/)
- [StatsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd)
- [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com)
- [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/)

Some of which have Docker images that you can use to play with.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is of huge help. Can you please point me to one which is best (as in documentation with showing max details) and easy to setup/learn (and open source) as want to speedup my development cycle?

Comment: You can't go wrong playing with this Activator template, which has a Docker image: https://github.com/muuki88/activator-akka-kamon (it has an associated blog post)

Comment: Thanks. Play and akka is making me feel awesome :)